# How is changing array dimension exempted from strict alias rules?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, undefined-behavior, strict-aliasing

Does the standard allow us to reinterpret dimension of array (while maintaining the underlining type, of course)

```
template<int M, int N, typename T>
auto& arr_reinterp(T& arr1d) {
    using U = std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*arr1d) >;
    return reinterpret_cast<U(&)[M][N]>(arr1d);
    // U(&)[M][N], ironically UB in this case?
}
```

just to use it like this?

```
        char a[100]{};
        std::iota(std::begin(a),std::end(a),0);
        auto& b = arr_reinterp<5,20>(a); // char (&b)[5][20]
        for (const auto& each_firstcol : b) {
            for (const auto& item : each_firstcol)
                std::cout << std::setw(4) << static_cast<int>(item); // int-ization
            std::cout << '\n';
        }
```

If this is allowed, how is this exempted from strict alias rules? Please explain.

[godbolt.org/g/E5JGuQ](https://godbolt.org/g/E5JGuQ)

[wandbox.org/permlink/vfHHNbbV5i7KfeM9](https://wandbox.org/permlink/vfHHNbbV5i7KfeM9)

Comment: Something tells me it's not allowed.

Comment: Array types with different size are different types. There are no exception to the strict aliasing rule for arrays.

Comment: @Oliv so if one would like it in another dimension, only way is to allocate the new one, then iterate the old one to assign each value into all new positions oneself?

Comment: @sandthorn, No, just implement a class holding a pointer to the first element of the array and provides and overload of `operator []`. Look for array_view on internet, maybe some of the implementations are what you are looking for.

Comment: If instead of `b[x][y]` you do `a[x * N + y]` it is ok. And if you make `arr_reinterp` a class instead of a function, you can hide the transformation inside it.

Comment: The standard's not really clear on this matter

Comment: @Oliv it is not possible to access arrays by value however, so it is hard to argue any strict aliasing violation. Accessing an element doesn't implicitly access the entire array of which that is an element

Comment: @M.M. I think [this linked rule](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.object#8) applies very well here. Why do you think it would not?

Comment: @BoPersson: When C was designed, there was no need to syntactically distinguish between accessing the Nth item within a 2D array, versus accessing the Nth item within the first row of the array, since both operations would compute and use the same address.  The maintainers of the C Standard missed an opportunity to say that `arrayLvalue[x]` would *not* decompose `arrayLvalue` to a pointer, but was instead would access parts of that array.  This would make it possible to have arrays of things without addresses [e.g. bitfields or register-qualified objects], and also provide a nice...

Comment: ...way to let a compiler distinguish between array accesses that can be guaranteed not to alias things outside a particular array, versus those that might need to access other parts of a larger enclosing object.  Given `int arr[4][4]`, it would have been easy (and IMHO natural) to say that `arr[y][x]` can only access items in row y of the array, but `((int*)(arr[y]))[x]` would be able to access element `y*4+x` of the overall array, even if x was negative or greater than 3, provided y is in the range 0..3 and `y*4+x` is in the range 0..15.

Comment: @BoPersson: Unfortunately, I don't think either the C Standard nor the C++ Standard has recognized the need for two different forms of indexing semantics, and thus does not provide for them.